# kendo UI widgets with Ionic 2: how to import styles?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, ionic2

I want to use **kendo UI widget** so I'm trying first with simple button integration.

Here is the link for [Kendo](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/getting-started) for integration with Angular 2.

I followed each steps but can not import following

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import "~@progress/kendo-theme-default/scss/all";
```

into the **theme/variables.scss**, getting following error:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: ~/@progress/kendo-theme-default/scss/all Parent style sheet:
```

I don't know either need to look into **webpack file** or anything else  or how `@import "ionic.globals";` import statement works?

Any help would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 1):

**install** 
  npm install -g node-sass

**in styles.scss; write this**

/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

@import "../node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/scss/all.scss";

**then execute**
node-sass styles.scss styles.css

**and finally** 
put this in index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
```

**when execute the server with ng serve**
 **comment**

```
  /*@import "../node_modules/@progress/kendo-theme-default/scss/all.scss";*/
```

**because generate error.**

**the documentation.**
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/styles-and-layout/sass-themes

pdt. sorry for my bad English

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped.